# In PHP how can access a property in an included file that was defined in the calling file?

Tags: php, html

If I have two files

**main.php**

```
<?php
    $title = "thisTitle";
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/aatemplate.php";
?>
```

**aatemplate.php**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/common/head.php";?>
        <title>$title</title>
    </head>
</html>
```

How can I make the '$title' in the template file be replaced with the $title set in the main.php so that it becomes:

```
<title>thisTitle</title>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you include a file that's will be access to main file & previous included files variables.

Change

```
<title>$title</title>
```

to

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to PHP variables that are declared by using the echo statement

Replace with  `<?php echo $title; ?>`